# Reducing number of connections required in FME

Tags: fme-form

With FME 2017 I have to export multiple (205) feature types coming from an SDE Database. I have loaded them into Workbench which creates 205 separate Readers and I now have to create a writer for each one to export into a different format which is obviously very time consuming.

Which is the best method for outputting feature types individually as in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean a ***writer*** for each one (your question says *reader*)?

To create multiple writers is a simple task using a fanout tool.

[image]

Here I am writing each postcode from an address dataset to a separate GML file. So you could point all your data sources into a single feature type on a single writer and - by setting a fanout - create a separate writer/output for each at run time.

Probably the best way is to use *fme_dataset* or *fme_feature_type* as part of the fanout expression

Obviously , this does mean you need all of your source data tables to have the same attribute schema as defined in the one output feature type.

If that's not the case then you'll need to flick the switch and make it a dynamic translation:

[image]

Here I'm saying to write to a different output, but using the same schema as the original table had for everything (so if I had multiple source tables they would still get the correct schema)

Comment: Here's a demo movie to show the technique in more detail: https://www.screencast.com/t/FfD5z5Yw5

Comment: Your Video really told me the solution. Thanks very much Mark!!

Comment: @MarkIreland You should include the video in your answer as it appears that may have been part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is 223 Feature Types going from Oracle Spatial to Oracle Spatial but in GENERIC Mode.

Tip:
**Use the Feature Type Connections Window to 'Auto Connect'**
(a real time saver, this is based on the reader names to match exactly with the writer table names )

[image]
Generic Writer Mode

[image]

Comment: Took less than 5 minutes to set up this workspace process.

Comment: Thanks for your description. How did you manage to create the corresponding writers?

Comment: Robert I have added an extra image with the Writer in Generic Mode